# How does isset not throw an error when evaluating array properties?

Tags: php, isset

Whenever I try to access a property of an array that does not exist, php throws an ERROR_NOTICE that reads like this:

`Notice: Undefined offset: BLANK in BLANK on line BLANK`

```
$a = array("a","b","c");

$a[4]; //throws an error
```

Instead, if I use `isset` to test for the existence of this property, this error is not thrown.

```
$a = array("a","b","c");

isset($a[4]); //does not throw an error
```

Since php does evaluate arguments before passing them to a function, how does isset avoid to throw an error?

Comment: `isset` isn't a function, even if it looks like one.

Comment: Ha! that was easy, i must have missed that in the documentation!

Comment: can you add a real code example making this more usefull for future readers

Comment: yeah, let me update the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) isn't a function but a *language construct*:

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions.

It's not called the way functions are called but handled specially by the language. The same goes for `empty`.